# Why is this onClick event handler firing twice in my create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

can someone tell me why is this "upvote" onClick handler firing twice?
the logs would indicate it's only running once but the score it controls increases by 2

```
export default class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      jokes: [],
    };
    this.getNewJokes = this.getNewJokes.bind(this);
    this.retrieveJokes = this.retrieveJokes.bind(this);
    this.upVote = this.upVote.bind(this);
  }
upVote(id) {
    this.setState(state => {
      //find the joke with the matching id and increase score by one
      const modifiedJokes = state.jokes.map(joke => {
        if (joke.id === id) {
          
          joke.score = joke.score + 1;
          
        }
        return joke;
      });
      console.log(modifiedJokes);
      return { jokes: modifiedJokes };
    });
  }
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Container</h1>
        {this.state.jokes.map(joke => (
          <Joke
            key={joke.id}
            id={joke.id}
            joke={joke.joke}
            score={joke.score}
            upVote={this.upVote}
            downVote={this.downVote}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

on the other hand if I rewrite the handler this way, then it fires only once

```
upVote(id) {
    const modifiedJokes = this.state.jokes.map(joke => {
      if (joke.id === id) {
        joke.score = joke.score + 1;
      }
      return joke;
    });
    this.setState({ jokes: modifiedJokes });
  };
```

Comment: where do you call the callback `upVote()` ? what is `Joke` component?

Comment: Maybe it liked the joke a little too much?

Comment: have you tried setting breakpoints?  It will help you see which code is running and when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that in the first case, you are also modifying the state directly, when you do joke.score = joke.score + 1;

Because you are doing this mapping directly on state array variable, and in Javascript, when using array, you are only working with pointer to that array, not creating a copy of that array.

So the mapping function probably takes a shallow copy of the array, and there's where problem happens.

You can use lodash to create a deep copy of the state array before you going to work with it, which will not cause your problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-babbage-lorlm

Comment: this is the correct answer. I'll answer my own question and elaborate

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because React uses synthetic events which are reused when it’s handling is done. Calling a function form of `setState` will defer evaluation (this can be dangerous when the `setState` call is event dependent and the event has lost its value).

So this should also work:

```js
this.setState((state,props) => ({ jokes: modifiedJokes}));
```

***I can't locate my source at the moment but, I remember coming across this a while back. I'm sure looking through the React Docs can provide a more in depth explanation***

Comment: Found the relevant [React `setState` documentation with example](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: it's the setState portion that fires twice I realized. The rest of the onclick handler just fires once...somehow? anyway as long as I apply the modifications to the new state outside of the setstate callback it works fine. But this defies the whole point of being able to modify state based on the old state which was why i am using the callback setstate instead of the regular one

Comment: Right, basically what I was saying too. The event handler might be getting reused after the state has been updated once. So the reuse makes it seem like it's been called a second time. If that makes sense? Good work with the debugging and good to leave the answer for other :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. I'll post an answer just in case anyone happens to stumble into this upon encountering the same problem.

When in debug mode react will run certain functions twice to discourage certain operations that might result in bugs. One of these operations is directly modifying state.
when doing

```
this.setState(state => {
      //find the joke with the matching id and increase score by one
      const modifiedJokes = state.jokes.map(joke => {
        if (joke.id === id) {
          
          joke.score = joke.score + 1;
          
        }
        return joke;
      });
      console.log(modifiedJokes);
      return { jokes: modifiedJokes };
```

the map function returns a new array where every elements points to the **same** element in the original array. therefore by doing

```
state.jokes.map(joke => {
        if (joke.id === id) {          
          joke.score = joke.score + 1;          
        }
```

I was effectively directly modifying the state. React runs the setstate function twice in debug mode to weed out this kind of operation.

so the correct "react way"of modifying the attribute of an object nested in an array is to do this instead

```
this.setState(state =>{
   let modifiedJokes = state.jokes.map(joke => {
        
        if (joke.id === id) {          
          return {...joke, score:joke.score+1}         
        }
        else{ return joke}
   })
   return {jokes:modifiedJokes}
})
```

this way when encountering an element with the correct ID a copy is made of that specific element and the score of that copy is increased by one which doesn't impact the actual element which is still in the state left untouched until it is modified by react committing the new state